# How to enable dblclick event on elements which was binded with JQuery UI Selectable plugin?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, selectable

In my case,I have an UL with `JQuery UI Selectable` plugin applied,but at the same time ,I want the item witch was binded with `selectable plugin` was doing something when I `double click` this item.But it seems that the `JQuery UI Selectable plugin had block the dblclick event`. So,how can I make it work?

E.g:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#selectable" ).selectable();

                $( "#selectable" ).dblclick(function(){
                    // do something here
                })
    });
    </script>

<ul id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're never going to be able to make a page work well when elements are trying to handle both single- and double-click. The code will be too complicated, browsers don't cooperate, and users will absolutely hate it.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

In jQuery you can link events, like this:

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable().dblclick();
```

Bit I'm not sure this will work, because both events are click events.

Comment: This is not "linking events". It's just calling two functions, one after the other. It's called "chaining" and has nothing to do with events.

Answer (score 17):

If you add .ui-selected to cancel options passed into selectable method then you can double click b/c it will not raise selecting event on .ui-selected items.

```
$('#selectable').selectable({ 
  cancel: '.ui-selected' 
});
```

Although, this does take away the ability to deselect a selected item. You could do the following to manually deselect

```
$('.ui-selected').on('click', function() {
  $(this)
    .removeClass('ui-selected')
    .parents('.ui-selectable')
    .trigger('selectablestop');

  // you might also want to trigger selectablestop.
});
```

Comment: I believe now with 1.7, the on() method for binding events should be used for the .ui-selected click, so that they can be made "delegated" which means that as elements gain and lose the .ui-selected class, they automatically gain and lose the event handler. That would look like:

$('#selectable').on('click', '.ui-selected', function() { ...

Comment: Updated the answer using .on method. Thanks Michael

Answer (score 7):

You just need to set the distance to a number > 0 to register clicks and double-clicks.

```
$("#selectable").selectable({
    distance: 1
});
```

See http://forum.jquery.com/topic/selectable-dosn-t-fire-click-event

Comment: This was a neat way of doing it but stops the mouse click selection

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#selectable li").mousedown(function(event) {
    if(event.which==1)
    {
        if($(event.currentTarget).data('oneclck')==1)
        {
            alert('click');

            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).data('oneclck', 1);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(event.currentTarget).data('oneclck', 0);
            }, 200);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not valid code. You must save `event.currentTarget` in local variable for it work fine. Plz fix it. You answer is most valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is because onmousedown triggers selection event (the dotted div that selects multiple selectable elements.) I had the same problem and i fixed it by adding a few lines of the code to the JQUERY UI library. What you have to do is to delay selection event by starting it after the mouse moves a few pixels. This allows you to double click element and still have the selection that is user friendly! :D

This is the part of the code that delays the selection and solves your problem:

```
<script>
    var content = $('#content').selectable();

    var _mouseStart = content.data('selectable')['_mouseStart'];

    content.data('selectable')['_mouseStart'] = function(e) {
        _mouseStart.call(this, e);
        this.helper.css({
            "top": -1,
            "left": -1
        });
    };
</script>
```

I found this workaround in this [post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/selectable-dosn-t-fire-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

I use this and I think it's the best solution.

```
$("ul").selectable({
    filter: "li"
});

$("ul").on("mousedown","li",function(e){
    var n = ($(e.toElement).is(".ui-selected")) ? 1 : 0;
    $("#filelist").selectable( "option", "distance", n );
});
```

When the user starts a click on a selected elements I set the `distance` to one so that the doesn't blocks the double click event, but I available if the user really starts selecting.