# jQuery UI event not firing without scrolling down in the browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

A jQuery UI 'dblclick' event fails to fire unless the web page is scrolled down a small amount from the top. Scrolling down allows the event to be fired but scrolling back to the top of the page reintroduces the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <style>
        #selectableTiles .ui-selected
        {
            background: black;
            color: white;
        }

        #selectableTiles
        {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 50 auto;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #selectableTiles li
        {
            margin: 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="">
        <p style="text-align:center; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px">
            You must have scrolled down.
        </p>
    </div>
    <ul id="selectableTiles">
        <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#selectableTiles").selectable();
        });
        $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                OK: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $(".ui-state-default").dblclick(function (event) {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("option", "title", event.target.textContent);
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
        });
    </script>
    <p class="clear">
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NbYDH/

The JSFiddle page above recreates the issue in IE. To recreate the issue with Firefox, right-click in the Result panel at the bottom right. Select 'This Frame' -> 'Show Only This Frame' (you will likely have to shrink the size of the browser window to introduce a scroll bar). I don't know about other browsers.

You will find that double-clicking on one of the panels only launches a dialog if the scroll bar is a little below the top of the page. This has been a bizarre issue to describe and recreate.

Comment: are you somehow assigning the both the `click` event and the `dblclick` event to the same tags? Maybe even without your knowledge (e.g. `selectable()` assigning the click and you are assigning the dblclick ?)

Comment: I've tested it on different events e.g. also single click, and seen the same problem. I've also tried it double-clicking on a selected and unselected tile alike. The only common factor I can find that affects if the dialog is launched is to do with the scrollbar position. You could be on to something though, I'll have a think.

Comment: [In your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbYDH/1/) I removed the `selectable()` The dblclick then works as expected without scrolling. Must be something in the `selectable()` causing this

Comment: Aaah, interesting. Ok, this is progress. I still need the element to be selectable but I'm a little closer to understanding a way around the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more investigation with the `selectable()` I ran into [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7907812/474535)
I combined that with [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NbYDH/4/) and it works. Note that I put everything into one `document.ready()`.

According to the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-cancel), the `cancel` prevents selecting if you start on elements matching the selector. However it requires anohter `click` event handler to unselect the things again.

Below the code that works for your situation

```
$("#selectableTiles").selectable(
    {cancel: '.ui-selected'}
);
$(document).on('click','.ui-selected',function() {
   $(this)
    .removeClass('ui-selected')
    .trigger('selectablestop');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your perseverance bart, that's great.