# Why does jQuery selectable break this click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple dblClick function working. I need to make my canvas div selectable using jQuery UI but doing so breaks the dblClick function.

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div class="trigger">Click me</div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#canvas').selectable();

$('.trigger').dblclick(function() {
    $('.box').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Txrcq/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar [post discussing the incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133966/how-to-enable-dblclick-event-on-elements-which-was-binded-with-jquery-ui-selecta) of `.selectable()` and `.dblclick()` on *a single DOM element*, and I suspect something similar is happening here. If you cancel the `.ui-selected` event, you'll be able to get back your double-click:

```
$('#canvas').selectable({ 
   cancel: '.ui-selected' 
});
```

Here's a [new Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgbeldock/P7JAF/) showing the double-click working now.

Comment: Thanks mate, it's perfect. What exactly does cancel do? That other answer says "it will not raise selecting event on .ui-selected items." But double clicking .trigger does actually make it selected.....

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.trigger').dblclick(function() {
$('.box').toggleClass('active');
});

$('#canvas').selectable({ cancel: ".trigger" });
```

Answer (score -2):

Here I fixed, it works now. Not sure why you're making your canvas selectable.

I removed the selectable class, and added the .on event :

```
$('.trigger').on('dblclick',function() {
    $('.box').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Try it with the code above. Please care to explain why you're doing the selectable() to the canvas.

Comment: I'm creating the trigger divs dynamically and I want each of them to be selectable. They will all live inside the canvas div. So adding the selectable class to canvas makes all children selectable?

Comment: Well if you could've specified that you needed it to be selectable for that reason that could've been a lot better. Please modify your answer so that people see that. Also, when you make a div selectable is the div per se, not the children.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct? I think making the canvas div selectable is correct? It seems to be working anyway.