# JQuery Cannot bind click event on selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, selectable

This should be very simple, but I am unavailable to retrieve click event and fire a function on a [`selectable`](http://jqueryui.com/selectable/) item for JQuery UI.

```
<div id="a">
<ol id="selectable-a">
  <li class="a-item">1</li>
  <li class="a-item">2</li>
  <li class="a-item">3</li>
  <li class="a-item">4</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#selectable-a").selectable();

$("li .a-item").click(function () {
  console.log("Executing command");
});
```

But the click event is never fired.

I have look into Google for that.

- try to replace `.click(` by `.bind('click',` but it does not change anything
- [In the jquery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/selectable-dosn-t-fire-click-event) they raise this problem and someone gives a solution tweaking the inner functionning, which does not work for me `(content.data('selectable')` is always undefined, no matter what)
- Setting the distance to 1, meaning that the user needs to move a mouse by 1 pixel so that the event is fired, is a bad idea.
- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5133966/1287856) does not have any satisfactory answer. Namely, I don't just want to get the click event on a selected item, but on any item.

Any idea on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$("li.a-item")` instead of `$("li .a-item")`

The first one looks for a li with the a-item class ; the second looks for an element with the a-item class inside a list element.

Comment: This solution would work for `mousedown` but unfortunately neither for mouseup nor click.

Answer (score 1):

This would work for:

```
<ol id="selectable-a">
  <li><div class="a-item">1</div></li>
</ol>
```

For yours, use:

```
$("li.a-item").click(function () {
  console.log("Executing command");
});
```

or even just

```
$(".a-item").click(function () {
  console.log("Executing command");
});
```

if you don't use `.a-item` elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following jQuery selector it works:

```
$("#selectable-a li").click(function () {
   console.log("Executing command");
});
```

This has the added benefit that you don't need an extra class for the list items anymore

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/9brPn/1/

Answer (score 1):

Automatically, the selectable adds a helper div to display a lasso with the class `.ui-selectable-helper`. This helper div is positioned right under the mouse. My best guess is that it's created on a mousedown and then interferes with the clicking.

I am working on a better fix, but for now, I am using this:

```
.ui-selectable-helper{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Also, change your selector to : `$("li.a-item")` And NOT $("li .a-item")

> [notice the space is not correct in your code]

[EDIT]
Better fix : From http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-distance

Add the option distance into your initialization as `$("#selectable-a").selectable({distance:10});`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem bro! I found the perfect solution:

My code was:

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable();
$('li.slot').on('click', function() {
    var selected_date = $(this).attr('data');
    console.log('selected item: ' +  selected_date); // open the console to see the selected items after each click
    $('#appointment_start').val(selected_date);
});
```

And now is:

```
$( "#selectable" ).selectable({
    selected: function( event, ui ) {
        var selected_date = $(ui.selected).attr('data');
        console.log('selected item: ' +  selected_date); // open the console to see the selected items after each click
        $('#appointment_start').val(selected_date);
    }
});
```

For me it works perfectly :)