# jQuery UI Selectable - mouseup is not triggered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

I have a list of items, to click drag and select I have used jQuery UI Selectable. The selection part is working smooth but I have delegated "mousedown" and "mouseup" events to the list of items, but the "mouseup" event is not triggered when I include jquery-ui.css file.

**HTML**

```
<div id="favoritelist">
    <span>This is favorite list</span>
    <ol id="selectable">
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#favoritelist').on("mouseup", function(){
    console.log('in favoritelist mouseup');
});

$('#favoritelist').on("mousedown", function(){
    console.log('in favoritelist mousedown');
});

$( "#selectable" ).selectable();
```

I have included the following files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

The mouseup event is not triggered when I include "jquery-ui.css" file. 
But when I remove the "jquery-ui.css" file the mouseup event is triggered properly and the selection is also working as expected.

I am confused why mouseup event is not propagating when I include the jquery-ui.css file.

JSBIN [LINK](https://output.jsbin.com/mevuce)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue/behavior has been discussed both here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246879/jquery-cannot-bind-click-event-on-selectable) and in the jQuery [forums](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/selectable-dosn-t-fire-click-event) & [issue tracker](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4219) - it boils down to the fact that there is a helper DIV that gets injected to display the visual "lasso" a user would see if click-and-dragging around the selectable items. This lasso DIV sits between the mouse & the selectable element and thus interferes with the mouseup event.

All links referenced suggest two options:

1. Use the optional `distance` [initialization parameter](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#option-distance) on the selectable widget, OR
2. Use the following CSS override: `.ui-selectable-helper{pointer-events:none}`

I find the latter to be more reliable, though the former is the technically preferred route.